# Computing time complexity and computational cost in non-abelian group based computation

Tags: group-theory, algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, semidirect-product

I came across the following questions regarding the time complexity and the computational cost. They are related to computations in non-abelian groups.

Suppose $H \rtimes_{\phi} K$ is a semidirect product of two finite groups, say $H$ and $K$. For an element $(h,k) \in H \rtimes_{\phi} K$, the inverse is $(\phi_k^{-1}(h^{-1}), k^{-1})$. If a person chooses any element $(h,k) \in H \rtimes_{\phi} K$ and compute its inverse, how can I explain about the time complexity and the computational cost of that computation?

And next if he computes, $(\phi_k^{-1}(h^{-1}), k^{-1})(h_1,k_1)$ for some $(h_1,k_1) \in H \rtimes_{\phi} K$, then what is the time complexity and the computational cost?

$(\phi_k^{-1}(h^{-1}), k^{-1})(h_1,k_1) = (\phi_k^{-1}(h^{-1}) \phi_{k^{-1}}(h_1), k^{-1} k_1)$

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: At very least, this depends on how $H$, $K$ and $\varphi$ are given. Are they matrix groups? Permutation groups? Group presentations?

Comment: More precisely, the formula looks like this
$$
(h,k)^{-1}=(\phi_{k^{-1}}(h^{-1}),k^{-1}).
$$
Therefore, the cost of computing is equal to the sum of the costs of computing
the inverse in groups $H$ and $K$ and the cost of computing $\phi$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RobertChamberlain I can say they are taken as permutation groups. So far I didn't consider a specific group. Does it require to also know specifically what the group is, like $K \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$ or something like that?  Another small question. Suppose there are several sets $S_1=\{a_1, \cdots, a_i\}, S_2=\{b_1, \cdots, b_i\}, \cdots, S_k\{t_1, \cdots, b_i\}$. Each set contains $i$ elements from the above group $H \rtimes_{\phi} K$. A person is going to select one set out of these $k$ sets, say $S_j$. Then what is the time complexity?

Comment: Thanks a lot @kabenyuk does it involve a cost of applying $\phi$ to an element as well? Like cost of applying $\phi_{k^{-1}}(h^{-1})$ ? And to know the cost and time complexity exactly I have to know whet the groups are, as mentioned by Robert Camberlain in the above comments ?